# Transfering arguments in Automator's workflow . Python Shells

Tags: python, file, input, arguments, automator

[image]

**So i'm creating a workflow in Apple's Automator that uses Python scripts in the shell**

This is what each step is doing right now:

1 . I paste a column of names from excel

2 . Organizes them in a list ... e.g. ['a','b','c'] 
*. . . this is where it gets weird*

3 . I select a text file on the finder item which is an input in the 2nd python script (#4) but the problem is that I also need the list generated from #2 in my script

4 . This script is supposed to use the list from #2 and the file selected by #3

When I didn't have #3 in there it was working fine because I used the sys.argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B58oE.png) to get the variable to transfer but i don't know how to skip feeding that into "Ask for Finder Item" and straight into #4

**basically i'm having trouble inputing the list from the workflow into the script WHILE selecting a file for another variable so i can have:**

```
my_list = sys.argv[1] #from step 2
my_file = sys.argv[2] #selected from step 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you select "Ignore this action's input" in #3, it will just append the selected file(s) to output from script #2 as its output, so script #4 will get them.

The problem is that you get an implicit "Conversion from Text to Files/Folders" feeding #2 into #3. So, if #2's output is a list of strings that look like pathnames but aren't, they will get converted into pathnames to files that don't exist, which will get converted into references to files that don't exist, which will just get dropped when #3's output gets converted back to text for #4.

---

The easy way around this (conceptually easy; it does mean a bit of extra code…) is to have script #2 store the list in a temporary file, and print out the filename. That filename will pass through the conversions and come out the other end just fine, so script #4 can open and read the file to get the list back.

To take a silly example, let's say you were doing this:

```
import sys
new_list = sorted(sys.argv[1:])
print '\n'.join(new_list)
```

Instead, do this:

```
import sys
import tempfile
new_list = sorted(sys.argv[1:])
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(new_list))
    print f.name
```

Then, in script #4, instead of this:

```
import sys
new_list = sys.argv[1:-1]
step3 = sys.argv[-1]
```

… do this:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    new_list = list(f)
os.remove(sys.argv[1])
step3 = sys.argv[2]
```

Of course in a more realistic example, you'd probably want to use, e.g., `pickle.dump` instead of just `'\n'.join`, but this should be enough to show the idea.

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what i needed ! quick question . . . so i'm proceeding with my function and there is a part where i'm trying to  split the path using os.path.split(input) where the input is sys.argv[2] . . . it is getting an error for some reason ? i checked to make sure sys.argv[2] was a string and it looks good . i have no idea why dir,file = os.path.split(input) isn't working . . . it works in CodeRunner

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: What's the error? Can you post the relevant code somewhere? Are you sure you remembered to `import os.path`? (Automator fills in a few `import` statements for you automatically, but not that one.) If it's not something really trivial, this seems like you should create a new question, and get some other people's eyes on it instead of just mine.

Comment: hej, so i just tried import os.path and i got the same error . the hard thing about working in automator is that it tells you where the error is but only where the line is that errs . i explained everything in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970231/new-file-in-same-directory-as-input-file-python but i haven't heard from anyone regarding solutions . i checked out the sys.version and my terminal is running 2.7.3 and Automator is running 2.7.2 but i didn't think that should affect anything

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: That last point means that you've installed a third-party Python implementation, and modified your `$PATH` in some way that makes it take precedence over Apple's stock /usr/bin/python, which can lead to a whole lot of confusion (e.g., you install something with `easy_install` or `easy_install-2.7`, and it's not available to import when you just run `python` or `python2.7`)… but it's not going to cause _that_ problem.

Comment: @draconisthe0ry: Also, if you search around online, I think people have figured out how to add more "Shell:" options to the Run Shell Script action, which means if you want your third-party Python to be available in Automator, you can get it there… but you probably don't need it.