# New file in same directory as input file . Python

Tags: python, function, input, directory, automator

[image]

```
import sys,os

name_list = open(sys.argv[1]).read().split('\r')

os.remove(sys.argv[1])

input_file = (sys.argv[2])

def Extractor(input,output='query.txt'):
    query = open(input,'r').read().split('\r')

    dir,file=os.path.split(input)
    temp_out= os.path.join(dir,output)
    out_file=open(temp_out,'w')

print Extractor(input_file)
```

I have no idea why this isn't working . . .

i am trying to **create a new file in the same directory as the input file** but it is saying that there is an error . i'm not used to working in Automator's workflow but theoretically this should work since i've used this in python interpreters .

input_file = (sys.argv[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBNES.png)) is a string of the file location . when i print the query inside of the function it works fine but once i get to "dir,file = os.path.split(input)" **that's where the function fails** .

Why isn't this working ?

Error message from Automator isn't telling me much . . .:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What error message are you seeing?

Comment: i just updated the entry with the error messages

Comment: The picture isn't really showing the full traceback error, try running the script in a console and catch the full error (if that's even possible on mac)

Comment: As it is, `Extractor` isn't returning anything. So your print statement will return `None`.

Comment: i'm running the same script through CodeRunner and its running fine :/

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to get full tracebacks directly out of Automator… but you can do it manually. See [this example](http://pastebin.com/mmPza0za). Meanwhile, you might want to try breaking it up into subexpressions to see which one goes wrong: `print os.path`, `print os.path.split`, `print os.path.split(input)`.