# Analagous operations to achieve os.path.split in Python?

Tags: python, function, directory, operating-system, os.path

I have been using the Automator on OSX [according to previous questions] and **my `os.path.split` is not working** for some reason even though it is the same code that runs fine in CodeRunner and terminal...

Is there any other way to achieve this function:

```
import os
input = '/Users/Opus_Magnum/desktop/list.txt'
output = 'test_output.txt'

dir,file = os.path.split(input)
temp_out= os.path.join(dir,output)
out_file=open(temp_out,'w')

print dir
print file
print temp_out

>> /Users/Opus_Magnum/desktop
>> list.txt
>> /Users/Opus_Magnum/desktop/test_output.txt
```

**I'm basically trying to create a new file in the same directory as the input file**

I would prefer to know what could be causing my `os.path.split` function to not work but if something analogous is available then I guess that can work too .

Comment: how do you know its not working? what is it printing instead? is there an error? (define __not working__)

Comment: everything is working perfectly until i get to the line dir,file = os.path.split(input) . . . i checked to make sure the input string is correct and everything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970231/new-file-in-same-directory-as-input-file-python

Comment: again you are only saying there is a problem, not what the problem is ... please post a traceback or tell us what happens that you are not expecting (ie the file gets created in directoy X when I expect directory Y)

Comment: again you are only saying there is a problem, not what the problem is ... please post a traceback or tell us what happens that you are not expecting (ie the file gets created in directoy X when I expect directory Y)

Comment: sorry about that :( automator doesn't tell me much in the log just tells me what line the error is in . when i run it in CodeRunner it runs fine . in automator its not printing anything it just stops running

Comment: yeah the link to the other question was more helpful (I clicked it after I berated you about not including the problem :P )

Comment: haha its ok. the answer yan gave helped me out to achieve what i was trying to achieve but i still have no idea why the os.path.split isn't working . i ran sys.version in my terminal and one in automator and they are running 2.7.3 and 2.7.2, respectively . i don't think that would matter but that is the only thing i could think of which may be causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.dirname()` to obtain the directory of the input file.

```
input = '/Users/Opus_Magnum/Desktop/list.txt'
input_dir = os.path.dirname(input)
output = 'test_output.txt'
temp_out = os.path.join(input_dir, output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir = os.path.dirname(input)
file = os.path.basename(input)
```

Analogous to

```
dir,file = os.path.split(input)
```